# Include interactive function in shiny to highlight "readlines" and "print"

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I have learned recently the bases of the application of shiny in RStudio and I see the global operation of this package.

But I don't find if what I want to do is possible even if I have found some interesting elements on websites.

I will explain my problem :

I have already programmed functions in R which interact with the users with function `readlines(prompt="")` and `print"` but to avoid people going on R I want to make shiny application.

I have found the way to include a script of a function in the shiny system :
http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/

But I don't manage to create a window on shiny which allows to launch my script even if I have try many reference functions of this website : 
http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/

as `renderPrint`, or `renderText`.

PS : I want to do that to make the least modifications on the many functions I have built.

Example : 
I have already do that :

```
library(Shiny)
dir="MyDirectory"
source(paste(dir,"/PathToMyFunction/MyFunction.r",sep=""))
#############################################################
server<-function(input, output) {

output$Nettoyage<- renderPrint({

step1 <- switch(input$STEP, 
               "TRUE" = TRUE,
               "FALSE" = FALSE)

step2 <- switch(input$STEP, 
                "TRUE" = TRUE,
                "FALSE" = FALSE)

MyFunction(dir=dir,STEP1=step1,STEP2=step2) 

})
}
#############################################################
ui<-navbarPage('Outils', id="page", collapsible=TRUE, inverse=FALSE,
           tabPanel("Onglet1",
                    tabsetPanel(
                      ###
                      id='Onglet1_tabs',                           
                      ###
                      tabPanel("SubOnglet2",

                        fluidPage(titlePanel("Tâche de l'onglet 2"),
                           sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                               helpText("Iteractive texte"),

                                selectInput(inputId ="STEP1", 
                                  label = "Application première étape",
                                  choices = c("TRUE", "FALSE"),
                                  selected = "Etape 1 appliquée"),

                                selectInput(inputId ="STEP2", 
                                   label = "Application deuxième étape",
                                   choices = c("TRUE", "FALSE"),
                                   selected = "Etape 2 appliquée"),
                                 ),

                                 #mainPanel(plotOutput("Nettoyage"))
                                 #mainPanel(textOutput("Nettoyage"))
                                 mainPanel(printableOutput("Nettoyage"))
                                 #mainPanel(printoutput ("Nettoyage"))

                               )

                      )     
                 )
             )
#############################################################
```

And when I launch the function "ui", I have the following error message :

```
Error in tag("form", list(...)) : argument is missing, with no default
```

And I don't understand the problem but I think that is the "renderPrint" and "printableOutput" which are not suitable functions.

I hope that my problem is accurate enough.

NB : If my explications on the work of "MyFunction" is not clear, I write an example of some of its lines :

```
MyFunction<-function(dir,STEP1=FALSE, STEP2=FALSE){
[...]
tab<- apply(Data,c(1,2),as.numeric)
print(tab)
[...]
Line<-readline(prompt="Select the good line : ")
Line<-as.numeric(Line)
[...]

}
```

And I would like to show up in shiny the "print" and the "readline(prompt="")"

If someone could help me, it would be very great

Comment: Hello everyone, actually the error message was due to the comma after ""Etape 2 appliquée"),". But my problem, now, is to identify the appropriate function to highlight the results of 'MyFunction'.